# is $\Bbb {Z} /p\Bbb{Z} [x] / (x^2+1) = \Bbb {Z} /p\Bbb{Z}[i]$?? p is prime

Tags: ring-theory

let $p$ be prime
$\Bbb {Z} /p\Bbb{Z} [x] / (x^2+1)$

any coset will be of the form $ax+b$. and $x^2 + 1 = 0$ so it is important that $x^2 = -1 = p-1$

$(ax+b)(cx+d) =(acx^2 + bd) + x(ad+bc) = (-ac+bd)+x(ad+bc)$ which is the same as complex multiplication.

Does this mean $\Bbb {Z} /p\Bbb{Z} [x] / (x^2+1)  =  \Bbb {Z} /p\Bbb{Z}[i]$ ??? I am unsure because I do not really understand quotient rings.

How does this connect to $\Bbb {Z} /5\Bbb{Z} [x] / (x^2+1) = [\Bbb {Z} /5\Bbb{Z} [x] / (x-2)] \times [\Bbb {Z} /5\Bbb{Z} [x] / (x-3)] = \Bbb {Z} /5\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb {Z} /5\Bbb{Z}$??

Comment: Well...yes. You're not doing anything else but calling $\,i\,$ to the element $\,x^2+\langle\,x^2+1\,\rangle\in\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)[x]/\langle\,x^2+1\,\rangle\,$ ... You could as well call it $\,j\,$ , $\,\omega\,$ or whatever. Of course, the choice of $\,i\,$ is wise since it is the square root of $\,-1\,$ there.

Comment: As DonAntonio said, it is not unnatural to denote the coset $x+\langle x^2+1\rangle$ by $i$. But in the field $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ the coset of $-1$ alread has a square root. Two of them actually. This is because
$$(\pm)^2=4\equiv-1\pmod5.$$ That's exactly what the statement on your last line seeks to capture. The polynomial $x^2+1$ factors as
$$x^2+1=x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)=(x-2)(x-3).$$

Comment: if I define $\varphi : f(x) \rightarrow f(i) mod p $ then this is onto $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ because $f(a+bx)= (a+bi) mod p$

I can use the isomorphism theorem to say $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z [x] =\Bbb Z/pZ[i]?? $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\,x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3)\pmod 5\Longrightarrow \Bbb F_5[x]/\langle\,x^2+1\,\rangle\,$$

is not a field (not even an integral domain) , and in fact it is easy to see that

$$\Bbb F_5[x]/\langle\,(x+2)(x+3)\,\rangle\cong \Bbb F_5[x]/\langle x+2\rangle\times\Bbb F_5[x]/\langle x+3\rangle\cong \Bbb F_5\times\Bbb F_5$$

Since each factor in the middle is isomorphic, as rings, to the field $\,\Bbb F_5:=\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\,$ (why?)

Comment: because the remainder after dividing by $x$ is less than 1 or thus 0 so it must be constants, ie $Z_5$?

Comment: what happens if $x^2+1$ can't be factored so it's irreducible, then I can't use chinese remainder theorem. For example, $p = 3$.

Comment: Please fix the factorization. It is $x^2+1=(x-2)(x-3)4 or, if you prefer, $(x-2)(x+2)$ or $(x+2)(x+3)$. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what I was thinking of...fixed.